# TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. For A noob

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, hittest

So, basically I'm having this problem with hitTesting.With all the AS3 I've done, I've never come across this error.I'm working with drag and drop and essentially you have to drag the trash into the bin.Pretty straight forward.Here is the code that is messing up and is giving me the error:

```
    if(coin3.hitTestObject(wallet1)) {
coins +=1;
coin3.x -=7000;
}
```

So this error is really annoying me and I need it fixed, it's destroying my game! I haven't assigned the object to a variable or datatype, just that straight forward.How do I fix this? I don't know what a null is!
Here is the entire code:

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
var coins:Number = 0;
var maxcoins:Number = 3;
coin2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, coin2drag);
function coin2drag(e:MouseEvent)
{
    coin2.startDrag();
}
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, coin2undrag);
function coin2undrag(e:MouseEvent)
{
    coin2.stopDrag();
}

coin3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, coin3drag);
function coin3drag(e:MouseEvent)
{
    coin3.startDrag();
}
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, coin3undrag);
function coin3undrag(e:MouseEvent)
{
    coin3.stopDrag();
}
coin4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, coin4drag);
function coin4drag(e:MouseEvent)
{
    coin4.startDrag();
}
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, coin3undrag);
function coin4undrag(e:MouseEvent)
{
    coin4.stopDrag();
}

coin2.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, coin2hit);
function coin2hit(e:Event)
{
    if (coin2.hitTestObject(wallet1))
    {
        coins +=  1;
        coin2.x +=  700000;
    }
    if (coins == maxcoins)
    {
        gotoAndStop(54);
    }
}


coin3.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, coin3hit);
function coin3hit(e:Event)
{
    if (coin3.hitTestObject(wallet1))
    {

        coins +=  1;
        coin3.x +=  700000;
    }
};


coin4.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, coin4hit);
function coin4hit(e:Event)
{
    if (coin4.hitTestObject(wallet1))

    {
        coins +=  1;
        coin4.x +=  700000;
    }
};
```

Comment: what version are you using. cuase I think it's a bug in flash cc 2015. Check this out: http://s6.uplod.ir/i/00707/wlot7x3fj87e.png

Answer (score 0):

This error means that an object you're trying to access to does not exist.
In this case, it means either coin3, wallet1 or coins variables haven't been properly created (initialized) before you try to use it.

Just make sure that coin3 and wallet1 are the real names of your movieclips and that they actually on the stage, and make sure coins is setted to any value at least once before using it (like coins = 0;);.

Comment: Can you please write some example code? coin3 and wallet1 are the movieclip and instance names.Please could you write an example! I'm really stuck (Thanks for your help)

Comment: Also, it says that the problem is coin3hit (the name of the function for the hitTest)

Comment: Just be sure when you're declaring the coins variable that you set it to any value : you need to have that line somewhere var coins:int = 0; before being able to use the coins variable anywhere else. (put it on top of the script using it). And please re-verify that the movieclips are effectively named coin3 and wallet1, I know a lot of times where typos have made developers tear off their hair :-)

Comment: Yes, all the movieclips have the proper name.Please, for the var I used var coins:Number = 0; and then var maxcoins:Number = 3; When coins == maxcoins it goes to the next frame.

Comment: as @MaxG is stating in the other answer, please verify that each instances of your coins & wallet that you placed on the stage are properly named (in the properties panel when you select a movieclip on the stage). Your code doesn't seem to have any error that I can notice...

Answer (score 0):

If you're instantiating your objects strictly with code, make sure you are classing your objects properly, and naming your variables accordingly... ie:

```
var coin3:Coin = new Coin;
```

where "coin3" is an instance of the class "Coin"... Depending on what you intend to do with the object, you may need to:

```
addChild(coin3);
//this may sit inside a function, or directly after the var is created, depending on what you're trying to do
```

Otherwise, if you're calling objects you've already physically placed on the stage, make sure it has an Instance name of whatever you're calling it. This is set in the properties window pane. Simply titling the MC "coin3" (or whatever) will not do it.

Without seeing more of the code though, it's hard to know what's happening. If the concept of class structure is new, then you should definitely read up on how that works, as it is essential to creating and managing objects properly with object oriented languages like AS3.

Comment: the entire code is now in the question, can u tell me what to do?

Comment: it looks like you're trying to store coins every you add them to the wallet yes? If so, a better way to do this, would be to turn coins into an Array and push the coins into the Array every time... Once your maxcoins is reached, you can clear the Array for the next run... Also why are you sending your coin to x=700000 ? are you just trying to get rid of it?

Comment: Yes I'm trying to get rid of it.Could you maybe change my code into arrays to show me what you mean, I don't quite understand.My email is simplyentertainingji@gmail.com <--- I will be really grateful!

Comment: What is breaking my game is, the error keeps coming after i leave the frame.Is there anyway i can remove the listener or something to make the error stop constantly coming.Because, the game is working but it's breaking because the error keeps swarming in.Help?

Answer (score 0):

This might get you started... Read about how Arrays work to better understand how to count and manage objects. This may or may not be ideal for whatever you're actually trying to do, but you can do some pretty nifty things with them... Also you mis-referenced one of your drag functions. I cleaned it up a bit to make it a little easier to manage.

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var coins:Array();
//this creates an empty array

var maxcoins:int= 3;

coin2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, drag);
coin2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, undrag);
coin3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, drag);
coin3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, undrag);
coin4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, drag);
coin4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, undrag);

// if only dragging one object at a time, then you can just put all your drags into two     functions

function drag(e:MouseEvent)
{
coin2.startDrag();
coin3.startDrag();
coin4.startDrag();
}

function undrag(e:MouseEvent)
{
coin2.stopDrag();
coin3.stopDrag();
coin4.stopDrag();
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

coin2.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, coin2hit);
function coin2hit(e:Event)
{
if (coin2.hitTestObject(wallet1))
{
    coins.push(coin2);
//this pushes the coin into the Array which will continue count until it is     cleared below ////

coin2.visible=false;
//setting coin2 to not be visible is simpler than moving it away, especially if the object is never being added again on stage. 
}

if (coins == maxcoins) // mind you this conditional will ONLY execute if coin2hit() is run.
{
    gotoAndStop(54);

    coins.pop(); //this clears the array ////
}
}


coin3.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, coin3hit);
function coin3hit(e:Event)
{
if (coin3.hitTestObject(wallet1))
{

    coins.push(coin3);
    coin3.visible=false;
}
};


coin4.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, coin4hit);
function coin4hit(e:Event)
{
if (coin4.hitTestObject(wallet1))

{
    coins.push(coin4);
    coin4.visible=false;
}
};
```

Comment: How to I add the coins into the array?

Comment: also, try using a trace to better pinpoint the problem... see how many functions you can get through before the error comes up. for example, in each function put a `trace(thisFunctionName, "or string")` or whatever, to see if it's actually getting to those functions. your trace will come up in the output window... If you're unclear on how a trace works, read up as this is also an essential part of debugging! It's quite simple :)

Comment: Comparison between a value with a static type array and a possibly unrelated type

Comment: is there any way to remove an event listener after the bug starts constantly coming.When I leave the frame, the bug constantly keeps coming.How do I stop this without debugging? like removing something?

Comment: try adding `var coinNum:int;

coin2=coinNum;
coin3=coinNum;
coin4=coinNum; ` to the top of the code and replace all the `push` functions with `coins.push(coinNum);` and see what happens...

Comment: you can `yourObjectOr_stage.removeEventListener` at any time

Comment: Scene 1, Layer 'Game', Frame 53, Line 5 1086: Syntax error: expecting semicolon before leftparen. <--- on the var coins:Array();

Comment: Scene 1, Layer 'Game', Frame 53, Line 4 1151: A conflict exists with definition coinNum in namespace internal.

Comment: try `var coins:Array = new Array();` instead

Comment: could you just tell me how i could remove the listener to stop the error constantly coming?

Comment: whenever the listener needs to go away (im assuming @maxcoins? ) add `whateverObjectNeedsToLoseTheListener.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.THE_REST_OF_THE_LISTENER, function); ` inside the function, or conditional

Comment: I'm really confused! I have a function, it works, but it displays the error, the error constantly keeps coming when I continue the game.It eventually crashes the game.I dont mind it displaying once but it keeps flooding in.What do I do?!

Comment: Please explain for a n00b im only 12

Comment: exactly when does it throw the error? this is where using a trace would be useful...so you know which part of the function is not getting executed. It also might not be a function causing the error, but rather, it is perhaps looking for an object or variable that is referenced wrong somewhere else.

Comment: then the issue may be with referencing wallet1. im not sure if it will make a difference but try switching it up so that its `wallet1.hitTestObject(coin2)` etc...